# Is there any way to use If..Then..Else in .htaccess on Apache 2.2.29 on Shared Hosting Environment?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, if-statement, shared-hosting, apache2.2

I learnt from this Q&A: [How to write "if...else" mod_rewrite statements in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528634/how-to-write-if-else-mod-rewrite-statements-in-htaccess) that it is possible to implement If statement in .htaccess but on Apache 2.4 and above.

I learnt from this Q&A: [htaccess if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992212/htaccess-if-statement), how to ipmlement If statement for Apache less than 2.4 versions. The answer by @julp almost solves my problem, but I don’t think I am allowed to do the “appending thing” on Shared Hosting.

Is there any workaround to using If..Then..Else in .htaccess on **Apache 2.2.29** on **Shared Hosting Environment**?

***Update:***

As instructed by @Thakkie, I am adding my specific requirements.

I am trying to host two domains from one shared hosting account. My .htaccess file is as follows:

```
<If “%{HTTP_HOST} == ‘domain2.com’”>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ domain2.com-directory/domain2-index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

</If>

<Else>

RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "<MyToken>"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com/domain1-index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/domain1-index.php$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

# Only proxy the request to Prerender if its a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]
</IfModule>

# Transfers to www.domain1.com when domain1.com is entered
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ domain1.com-directory/domain1-index.php [QSA,L]

</Else>
```

I am assigning one set of operation for domain1.com and another set of operation for domain2.com depending on the `HTTP_HOST` using `<If><Else>`.

I tried the above .htaccess file on my friend’s dedicated server, which is running Apache 2.4, and it worked.

But, unfortunately, my shared hosting account provider is running Apache 2.2.29 and thus the `<If></If>` and `<Else></Else>` is not supported.

What is the workaround to the `<If><Else>` in my situation?

Comment: IF ELSE directives are not available on 2.2. You need apache 2.4+ to use them.

Comment: @starkeen Yes, I understand. But is there any workaround?

Comment: You will need to post an precise and complete description and an example  because any workaround would be specific to what your needs are.

Comment: @Thakkie Description added...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most perfect solution, but it worked for me.

I was actually using the `<If><Else>` statement to perform domain specific actions.

As the `<If>` statement is not allowed in Apache 2.2.29, I appended `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname.com$ [NC]` before every `RewriteRule` which I wanted to be domain specific.

Thus

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ domain2.com-folder/domain2-index.php [QSA,L]
```

Becomes

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ domain2.com-folder/domain2-index.php [QSA,L]
```

The above lines mean: IF (the requested filename does not exist) AND (the `HTTP_HOST` is `www.domain2.com`) THEN use the `RewriteRule`.

Essentially, I used the `RewriteCond` to perform the function of the `<If>` operator, usable in Apache 2.4 or higher.

Now, the entire .htaccess file:

```
RequestHeader set X-Prerender-Token "<MyToken>"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain2.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ domain2.com-folder/domain2-index.php [QSA,L]

# Since I want the HTTPS to be domain specific
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(domain1.com|www.domain1.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com/domain1-index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/domain1-index.php$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_proxy_http.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_

# Only proxy the request to Prerender if its a request for HTML
RewriteRule ^(?!.*?(\.js|\.css|\.xml|\.less|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.gif|\.pdf|\.doc|\.txt|\.ico|\.rss|\.zip|\.mp3|\.rar|\.exe|\.wmv|\.doc|\.avi|\.ppt|\.mpg|\.mpeg|\.tif|\.wav|\.mov|\.psd|\.ai|\.xls|\.mp4|\.m4a|\.swf|\.dat|\.dmg|\.iso|\.flv|\.m4v|\.torrent|\.ttf|\.woff))(.*) http://service.prerender.io/https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$2 [P,L]
</IfModule>

# Transfers to www.domain1.com when domain1.com is entered
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain1.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ domain1.com-folder/domain1-index.php [QSA,L]
```

P.S. I request the seniors to please rectify my description, if you feel it is inaccurate.